# How I can stop async.queue after the first fail?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I want to stop of executing of my async.queue after first task error was occurred. I need to perform several similar actions in parallel with the concurrency restriction, but stop all the actions after first error. How can I do that or what should I use instead?

Comment: Interesting question. I am afraid you can't do it with `async.queue` even though other `async` functions (e.g. `each`) allow you to do that. You can check `async.queue` code here: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js and you will see there is no error handling. I would suggest reviewing your requirements as you might be able to _replace_ `async.queue` with, say, `async.eachLimit` (https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) and have needed functionality i.e. stop execution upon the first failure.

Comment: If they are executed concurrently how to stop the rest when one of them returns error.

Comment: None of these answers seem satisfactory, anyone got something new/better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you fired 5 parallel functions, each will take 5 seconds. While in 3rd second, function 1 failed. Then how you can stop the execution of the rest?

It depends of what those functions do, you may poll using setInterval. However if your question is how to stop further tasks to be pushed to the queue. You may do this:

```
 q.push(tasks, function (err) {
    if (err && !called) {
      //Will prevent async to push more tasks to the queue, however please note that
      //whatever pushed to the queue, it will be processed anyway.
      q.kill();

      //This will not allow double calling for the final callback
      called = true; 


      //This the main process callback, the final callback
      main(err, results);
    }
  });
```

Here a full working example:

```
var async = require('async');

/* 
   This function is the actual work you are trying to do.
   Please note for example if you are running child processes
   here, by doing q.kill you will not stop the execution 
   of those processes, so you need actually to keep track the 
   spawned processed and then kill them when you call q.kill 
   in 'pushCb' function. In-case of just long running function,
   you may poll using setInterval
*/
function worker(task, wcb) {
  setTimeout(function workerTimeout() {   
    if (task === 11 || task === 12 || task === 3) {
      return wcb('error in processing ' + task);
    }

    wcb(null, task + ' got processed');

  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}


/*
  This function that will push the tasks to async.queue,
  and then hand them to your worker function
*/
function process(tasks, concurrency, pcb) {
  var results = [], called = false;

  var q = async.queue(function qWorker(task, qcb) {

    worker(task, function wcb(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return qcb(err); //Here how we propagate error to qcb
      }

      results.push(data);

      qcb();
    });

  }, concurrency);

 /*
   The trick is in this function, note that checking q.tasks.length
   does not work q.kill introduced in async 0.7.0, it is just setting
   the drain function to null and the tasks length to zero
 */
  q.push(tasks, function qcb(err) {
    if (err && !called) {
      q.kill();
      called = true;
      pcb(err, results);
    }
  });

  q.drain = function drainCb() {
    pcb(null, results);
  }
}

var tasks = [];
var concurrency = 10;

for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i += 1) {
  tasks.push(i);
}

process(tasks, concurrency, function pcb(err, results) {
  console.log(results);

  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

async documentation on github page is either outdated or incorrect, while inspecting the queue object returned by async.queue() method I do not see the method kill().

Nevertheless there is a way around it. Queue object has property tasks which is an array, simply assigning a reference to an empty array did the trick for me.

```
queue.push( someTasks, function ( err ) {

    if ( err ) queue.tasks = [];

});
```

Comment: is queue.drain() still called here?  I guess what I'm looking for is some sort of `finally` functionality.  I'm using drain to determine the queue is done (because of error or not)

Comment: I believe it can be easily tested... just empty the tasks array on the queue and do a debug log inside a drain callback ;) If I am not mistaken you should get drain callback called